# How to show india map on google maps in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to show India maps on Google Maps
My code is like this first

```
 GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:18.516726
                                                            longitude:73.856255
                                                                 zoom:3];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        //Scrollview
         mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 140, 750, 350) camera:camera];
    }
    else
    {
        //Scrollview
         mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 140, 550, 350) camera:camera];

    }
```

But When I used UIView and create it using IBOutlet like this

```
IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView;
```

Than the above code not work.How can I show the India map first by using above coordinate.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You need not create frame when you already have it in storyboard. Why are you creating its frame ?

Comment: are you creating a property ? Please show your storyboard.

Comment: @Priyal I need to add camera value like this  mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 140, 750, 350) camera:camera]; I am using .xib

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485459/how-to-show-india-map-on-google-maps-in-objective-c/42485683#42485683

Answer (score 1):

Get current Location coordinate and Pass on these camera position

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
float latitude;
float longitude;

coordinate = [self getLocation];
latitude = coordinate.latitude;
longitude = coordinate.longitude;
```

//pragma mark ----: GET Coordinate2D :----

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocation
{
  CLLocation *location = [_locationManager location];
  coordinate = [location coordinate];
  return coordinate;
}

  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kSCREEN_WIDTH,kSCREEN_HEIGHT);
  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude zoom:12];
  mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:frame camera:camera];
  mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
  mapView_.delegate = self;

 [mapView_ setCamera:camera];
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is frame over hear?

Comment: Please chek edit  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kSCREEN_WIDTH,kSCREEN_HEIGHT);

Comment: I just used your code [mapView setCamera:camera]; and its done. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a Sample Code:

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface ViewController ()<GMSMapViewDelegate>
{
    GMSMapView *mapView;
    GMSMarker *marker;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self showMarker];    
}

- (void)showMarker
{
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:18.516726 longitude:73.856255 zoom:3];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

```
@interface ViewController ()<GMSMapViewDelegate>
{

    GMSMapView *mapView_;
}


GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:18.516726
                                                                    longitude:73.856255
                                                                         zoom:3];

            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            {
                //Scrollview
                mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 140, 750, 350) camera:camera];
            }
            else
            {
                //Scrollview
                mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 140, 550, 350) camera:camera];

            }


              NSError *error;

            // Set the map style by passing a valid JSON string.
            GMSMapStyle *style = [GMSMapStyle styleWithJSONString:kMapStyle error:&error];

            if (!style) {
                NSLog(@"The style definition could not be loaded: %@", error);
            }
            mapView_.mapStyle = style;
            mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;

            [self.scrllView addSubview:mapView_];


            [_btnMap setTitleColor:[UIColor yellowColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            mapView_.delegate = self;


            CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
                                                                         18.516726,
                                                                         73.856255);


            GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
            marker.map = mapView_;
            marker.icon=[UIImage imageNamed:@"locationBlue"];
            marker.title = @"From";
```